# C# How to use 2 classes with the same properties without modifying them

Tags: c#

I have two identical classes in different namespaces:

```
namespace NP1 {
   public class AAA {
      public int A {get; set;}
      public int B {get; set;}
   }
}

namespace NP2 {
   public class AAA {
      public int A {get; set;}
      public int B {get; set;}
   }
}
```

They are in different files and they are autogenerated. I can't modify them.

Then I have two other files:

```
using NP1;

public class N1Helper {
   (...)
   var sth = new AAA(A: some_value, B: some_other_value);
   (...)
}
```

and

```
using NP2;

public class N2Helper {
   (...)
   var sth = new AAA(A: some_value, B: some_other_value);
   (...)
}
```

The skipped parts of these helpers are identical.

I'd like to simplify these two files and write the code only once. If the classes in these namespaces would implement an interface, I could do it.

Is there a way I can solve this problem...

- Using generics?
- Telling somewhere *a posteriori* that `NP1.AAA` and `NP2.AAA` implement a common interface? Something like using partial classes and appending the interface information in a latter stage, but I can't modify the autogenerated files.
- ...?

Comment: You'll have to wait for C# 12.0's support for `role` types.

Comment: @Dai what now? Got a link?

Comment: @CodeCaster https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/5497

Comment: What about using and adapter or a mapper? So every time you need an instance _NP1.AAA_ or _NP2.AAA_ you can convert it from one to another or vice-versa.

Comment: That's not going to help, `role` is just a superset of extension methods, it injects methods into foreign classes. It's absolutely not the equivalent of `concept` in C++, ie duck-typing, which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: Unless the two `AAA` classes share something in common, like an interface there is absolutely no way you can combine the two definitions and use some kind of hierarchy. C# is strongly typed and these two types are just different types that happen to have the same name and properties. 

Maybe a source generator can help here.

Answer (score 4):

> Using generics

Sure, just take the type as a generic argument. You just won't be able to actually use the generic argument, because it doesn't implement any interfaces:

```
public class NHelper<TAAA> {
   (...)
   // this is not going to work
   // var sth = new TAAA(A: some_value, B: some_other_value);
   (...)
}
```

> using partial classes [...] I can't modify the autogenerated files

Partial classes have to have the `partial` keyword, and your auto-generated classes don't. So no.

> ...?

Same no. C# isn't a duck-typing language like C++, it's a strongly typed language at every layer. You get exactly what you code, and if you don't feel like coding, you won't get anything.

Fix your auto-generated files.

Comment: _"C# isn't a duck-typing language like C++"_ - uhhhhhhhh

Comment: @Dai, if you have a question, ask it. I'll be glad to tell you about how templates and concepts work in C++, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

As Blindy mentioned you wont be able to make use of the generic type because it doesn't implement any interfaces. Although you could use the type to identify the *context* while taking advantage of `dynamic` to access/return the properties and methods in a common manner.

```
public class NHelper<TAAA>
{
    public dynamic GetSth(int some_value, int some_other_value)
    {
        dynamic someclass = typeof(TAAA) == typeof(NP1.AAA) ? new NP1.AAA() : new NP2.AAA();

        someclass.A = some_value;
        someclass.B = some_other_value;

        return someclass;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what 'sth' is I just followed your naming convention.

```
NHelper<NP1.AAA> helper = new NHelper<NP1.AAA>();
dynamic test = helper.GetSth(1, 2);
int A = test.A;
int B = test.B;
//int calc = test.Calculate();


NHelper<NP2.AAA> helper2 = new NHelper<NP2.AAA>();
dynamic test2 = helper2.GetSth(1, 2);
A = test2.A;
B = test2.B;
//calc = test2.Calculate();
```

Comment: This works only with c# 9.0, and sadly it's not my case, but it looks good...

Comment: `dynamic` has been around since C# 4.0, you should be able to use it just fine.